# Erro ao tentar instalar o mySQL-Connector-Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Tenho instalado a versão 3.6.5 do Python, e resolvi instalar o "mysql-connector-python-8.0.11-py3.6", porém ele retorna um erro de que não encontra tal versão instalada, será que preciso especificamente da versão 3.6.5 do mysql para funcionar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você adicionou o Python à variável `PATH` das variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: Adicionei, porém meu python esta intalado em %appdata%\local\programs a algum problema quanto a isto?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui, desinstalei esta versão e baixei a mesma versão só que 64bit, e defini a instalação para todos os usuários, vlw pela ajuda!